# Defining a constant in PHP

Tags: php

I define/initialize the constant like this in my code:

```
if(!define('CHECKLIST'))
{
    define("CHECKLIST",FALSE);
}
```

But it doesn't work and I got a warning error.

> Warning: define() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in PHP

Comment: You misspelled : it must be ' if(!defined ' with a d at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You check whether its [**`defined`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php) first.

```
if(!defined('CHECKLIST')) {
    define('CHECKLIST', FALSE);
}
```

Comment: @prodigitalson you're just seconds away also :)

Comment: From me +1 for fast answer :)